# How to detect the last element in the iteration of an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, iteration

So we have:

```
$myArray = ['KEY1' => 123, 'KEY2' => 456, 'KEY3' => 789];

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo($key . ' : ' . $value);
    
    // How to detect we reached the last $key/$value of the iteration?
 }
```

Without using a counter, how can we elegantly detect we reached the last key/value combination of the loop?  Note that the detection must be able to show the **key** and **associated** **value**.  Not sure if there is a better iteration option that will do the trick.

Comment: heh..no..because if we reached the last key/value, we must do something inside the loop.

Comment: Could you store the last key of the array to compare it at each iteration ?

Comment: Could use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php against `$key`.

Comment: ok ..I'll go with the array_key_last() function.  They actually made a function for that.  Cool!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
$myArray = ['KEY1' => 123, 'KEY2' => 456, 'KEY3' => 789];
$lstKey = array_key_last($myArray);

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' : ' . $value, "\n";

    if ($lstKey === $key)
       echo "Hey, Its the last one", "\n";
    // How to detect we reached the last $key/$value of the iteration?
}
```

Output,

```
KEY1 : 123
KEY2 : 456
KEY3 : 789
Hey, Its the last one
```

If u want old support upto `(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)`
You can also use something like this also,

```
$lstKey = array_keys(array_slice($myArray, -1))[0];
```

Comment: sidenote: [PHP => 7.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php)

Comment: `$lstKey = end(array_keys($myArray));` or `end($myArray);$lstKey = key($myArray);` can be interesting alternatives to "array_key_last" for PHP < 7.